# How to fix the error "index out of range"

Tags: python-3.x

I have to split the string with some "" in the string
I am a beginner in python, plz help me QQ
With the problem that line3 shows "index out of range"

windows

```
data = input().split(',')
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[i])):
        if data[i][j] == '"':
            data[i] += "," + data[i + 1]
            data.pop(i + 1)
            if data[i + 1][j] == '"':
                data[i] += "," + data[i + 1]
                data.pop(i + 1)

    print(data[i])
```

sample input:

```
'str10, "str12, str13", str14, "str888,999", str56, ",123,", 5'
```

sample output:

```
str10
"str12, str13"
str14
"str888,999"
str56
",123,"
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error occurs if you acces a list/string behind its data. You are removing things and access

> ```
> for i in range(len(data)):
>      ...
>      data[i] += "," + data[i + 1]
> ```

If `i` ranges from `0` to `len(data)-1` and you access `data[i+1]` you are outside of your data on your last `i`!

---

Do not ever modify something you iterate over, that leads to desaster. Split the string yourself, by iterating it character wise and keep in mind if you are currently inside `"  ... "` or not:

```
data = 'str10, "str12, str13", str14, "str888,999", str56, ",123,", 5' 

inside = False
result = [[]]
for c in data:
    if c == ',' and not inside:
        result[-1] = ''.join(result[-1]) # add .strip() to get rid of spaces on begin/end
        result.append([])
    else:
        if c == '"':
            inside = not inside
        result[-1].append(c)

result[-1] = ''.join(result[-1]) # add .strip() to get rid of spaces on begin/end
print(result) 
print(*result, sep = "\n")
```

Output:

```
['str10', ' "str12, str13"', ' str14', ' "str888,999"', ' str56', ' ",123,"', ' 5']

str10
 "str12, str13"
 str14
 "str888,999"
 str56
 ",123,"
 5
```

Add `.strip()` to the join-lines to get rid of leading/trailing spaces:

```
result[-1] = ''.join(result[-1]).strip()
```